# Manage multiple Role in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have created a roles and group table following things:

Group : Car
Role : Owner,Customer,Agent.

I have table where I include above things :

Group table

Role table

Role Group Mapping table

I have login screen in laravel default I just change a login layout using show_login() override a method. I want to implement role base login. Views are restricted to role (Owner,Agent,Customer).

Login Controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('customlogin');
    }


}
```

User Table Model :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',150)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('roleid')->unsigned();
            $table->rememberToken();
            /*Common Fields*/
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->integer('createdby');
            $table->integer('modifiedby');
            $table->string('publicguid');
            $table->string('privateguid');
            $table->timestamps();

           /*From other table */


        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission is what you are looking for

Comment: @DharmeshPatel Acutally looking same whatever rayrayray9151 added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a middleware for owner/agent/customer authentication. Do so by typing this:

```
php artisan make:middleware Owner
```

This creates a middleware file called Owner.php

Register the middleware on Kernel.php

```
'owner' => \App\Http\Middleware\Owner::class
```

Add the owner middleware to a route in route.php file

```
get('protected', ['middleware' => ['auth', 'owner'], function() {
    return "this page requires that you be logged in and an Owner";
}]);
```

Add the isOwner() method to User model for checking if it is admin or not.

```
public function isOwner()
{
    return $this->owner; // this looks for an owner column in your users table
}
```

You may do the same for other roles like agent/customer.

Comment: you are not getting me I think

Comment: I have updated. Where to put this . 'owner' => \App\Http\Middleware\Owner::class

Comment: What does this means, this looks for an owner column in your users table